I'm trying to make a scatter plot with error bars, and am having difficulty changing the black dot in the data point to blue
Here is my code. I've tried rearranging lines of code and turning the black dot blue. I would like to keep the data dots blue and have black error bars with the caps.
a = [85, 77, 77, 77, 70, 81, 70] #d57Fe measurement
b = [-0.322, -0.209, -0.085, -0.065, -0.077, -0.262, -0.066]
plt.scatter(a, b, s=200, color='cornflowerblue',  edgecolors='black')
c = [0.033, 0.036, 0.037, 0.04, 0.03, 0.032, 0.043] #errorbar

plt.errorbar(a, b, yerr=c, fmt='o', color='black', elinewidth=1, capsize=2,zorder=5)

plt.ylabel('\u03B4$^{57}$Fe', fontsize=18)
plt.yticks(fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel("Mg#", fontsize=18)
plt.xticks(fontsize=15)


To me your dots seem cornflowerblue all right, except for the black edge as you assumably intend. Can you clarify what exactly you want?
